# MbUnit.framework.dll Parallelizable attribute

Tags: unit-testing, parallel-processing, mbunit, gallio

the reference in my project was intially MbUnit.dll this was fine and allowed me to use [Parallelizable] attribute, but  to use [ForEachTest()], [DataFixture()] and [XmlDataProvider()] i need to use MbUnit.Framework.dll instead, however adding this reference to the project seems to remove the ability to use the [Parallelizable] attribute.

is there a way around this to use the benefits of both?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "remove the ability to use the [Parallelizable] attribute" ? What happens? It stops working? Error? Ignored?

Comment: The [Parallelizable] attribute is not accessible, as such it fails to compile. MbUnit.Framework.dll is a previous version and does not support the [Parallelizable]feature as stated below, looking through the link provided below i was able to reimplement the same functionality that was used in some old tests using MbUnit.dll which allowed me to also use the new features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parallelizable] is an MbUnit v3 feature.  It cannot be combined with MbUnit v2 features.

Instead of using [ForEachTest], [DataFixture], and [XmlDataProvider] from MbUnit v2, you should use the new data-driven testing features of MbUnit v3.

More information [here](http://www.gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3adata-driven_testing).